A Question Concerning the Properties of a Projective Cover
If $R$ is a left perfect ring, then any module $M$ over $R$ possesses a projective cover denoted by $P$. Furthermore, we can deduce that $P/\text{Rad} P$ is a semisimple module, where $\text{Rad} P$ represents the radical of $P$.
This raises the following question:
Is there a non-projective module $M$ over an indecomposable non-perfect ring such that its projective cover, denoted by $P$, satisfies the condition that $P/\text{Rad} P$ is not semisimple, where $\text{Rad} P$ represents the radical of $P$?

I won’t post this as an answer right now, as it’s almost certainly not the kind of example you want, and you may be able to make your hypotheses more precise to rule out this kind of example. But there are plenty of easy examples of non-projective modules $M_1$ over perfect rings $R_1$ (e.g., $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as a module over $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$), and plenty of examples of projective modules $M_2$ over non-perfect rings $R_2$ where $M_2/\text{Rad}M_2$ is not semisimple (e.g., $\mathbb{Z}$ as a module over $\mathbb{Z}$). Then $M_1\oplus M_2$ as a module over $R_1\times R_2$ works.

Thank you very much for your insightful suggestion. I have incorporated an additional condition stipulating that the ring must be indecomposable.

Let $R$ be the triangular matrix ring $\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}&\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\\0&\mathbb{Z}\end{pmatrix}$, and let $P$ be the projective left module $\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\\\mathbb{Z}\end{pmatrix}$.
Then $\operatorname{Rad}P=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\\0\end{pmatrix}$, so $P/\operatorname{Rad}P$ is not semisimple, but $P$ is the projective cover of $P/\operatorname{Rad}P$.

Thank you for your thoughtful response.
